# Defining SHELL: why some targets fail with error "invalid syntax" while another doesn't fail?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile as follows (excerpt):

```
# be a POSIX guy!
SHELL = /bin/dash

# avoid accursed tabs
.RECIPEPREFIX +=

PROJECT = my_project

# before-commit stuff
CHANGED_FILES = $(shell git ls-files --modified)

files ?= $(CHANGED_FILES)

lint:
    pyflakes $(files)

lint-all:
    pyflakes $(PROJECT)

STAGING_DB_PORT = 5437

staging-db-start:
    ssh -fNL 0.0.0.0:$(STAGING_DB_PORT):localhost:$(STAGING_DB_PORT) staging-db
    ss -tlpn sport eq :$(STAGING_DB_PORT)

staging-db-stop:
    ssh -O check staging-db
    ssh -O stop staging-db
    ss -tlpn sport eq :$(STAGING_DB_PORT)

staging-db-check:
    ss -tlpn sport eq :$(STAGING_DB_PORT)
    ssh -O check staging-db

.PHONY: lint, lint-all, staging-db-start, staging-db-stop, staging-db-check
```

When I run target, say `staging-db-check` it works just fine. Although, when I run target `lint`, it fails with error:

```
Makefile:2:9: invalid syntax
SHELL = /bin/dash
        ^
```

For me, it is very strange. I read docs, they say that you *always* must set `SHELL` variable, so I decided to do so. But I can not figure out where there is an error?

I have GNU make, version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make never generates diagnostics of form of:

```
Makefile:2:9: invalid syntax
SHELL = /bin/dash
    ^
```

But `pyflakes` does, which is the program run by your `lint` target's recipe:

```
lint:
    pyflakes $(files)
```

As you know, `pyflakes` lints Python source files. Your `$(files)`, as assigned
by:

```
# before-commit stuff
CHANGED_FILES = $(shell git ls-files --modified)

files ?= $(CHANGED_FILES)
```

expands to a list of files that includes `Makefile`. Your `Makefile` is not
a Python source file and the first line in `Makefile` that is not syntactically
valid Python is:

```
SHELL = /bin/dash
```

Here's a shorter makefile:

**Makefile**

```
# be a POSIX guy!
SHELL = /bin/dash

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo "Hello World"
```

with which to reproduce your error:

```
$ pyflakes Makefile
Makefile:2:9: invalid syntax
SHELL = /bin/dash
        ^
```

**Later**

> Is there a way to exclude non-python files from $files variable?

Yes. Assuming that Python files are files with the extension `.py`, change:

```
CHANGED_FILES = $(shell git ls-files --modified)
```

to:

```
CHANGED_FILES = $(filter %.py,$(shell git ls-files --modified))
```

See functions:

```
$(filter pattern...,text)
$(filter-out pattern...,text)
```

in [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
in [the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

And if you do that, maybe better change `CHANGED_FILES` to `CHANGED_PYTHON_FILES`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I never would have guessed that by myself.

BTW, is there a way to exclude non-python files from `$files` variable?

Comment: @tosh There is. See extended answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I also renamed variable :)